# Unix shell, ctrl-F no longer working with putty when ssh into RHEL box

Tags: emacs, putty

I swapped out a MacBookPro running OS X and Terminal.app - for a Windows 7 box using Putty.

ctrl-F no longer works on my shell prompts to move the cursor forward within a command line I'm editing:  I don't see any obvious settings in putty that are overriding ctrl-F being passed through to the terminal, and I don't see any obvious settings on the Unix terminal side that would not pass that raw character.  I don't want Windows to intercept any ctrl characters, since the terminal program (putty in this case) needs those.

All of the other keystrokes work as expected:
ctrl-A goes to the beginning of the line
ctrl-R reverse searches the bash history

**stty settings**

    `% stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke`

Putty version is

`PuTTY
Release 0.69-1
Build platform: 64-bit Windows
Compiler: Visual Studio, unrecognised version (_MSC_VER=1910)
Source commit: deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
© 1997-2017 Simon Tatham. All rights reserved.
Any suggestions appreciated`

Comment: This is not a unix/linux question.

Comment: Execute `read -n 1` and then press `^F`. Do you see any output?

Comment: **$ read -n 1**

No output.  I'm thinking that windows might have grabbed it, but there is no visual feedback from putty either.

Comment: Do not put the answer in the question. Make it a real answer. Otherwise this questions still looks unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was another post in **superuser.com** - the new putty installation had a terminal setting that needed to be changed to 'linux' rather than the default setting of 'xterm'

https://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash/104001#104001